# How to store an id from an API in a variable so that on an on click it can be used to locate information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

On an on click function I have album images from an API appear.  When clicking on the album image I have an overlay with the image.

I am trying to attach other information about the album to the overlay.  Is it possible to store the albums id in a variable so that on click just the information from one particular album is displayed? I can get all of the ids in this function as a variable, but can not work out how to store each one as an individual variable, to use on the on click function.  Any suggesstions are appreciated.

```
     function displayAlbums(data) {

                    var html = '<ul>';
                     $.each(data.tracks, function(i, eachAlbum) {
                     html += '<li class="albumImage">';
                     html += '<img src="' + eachAlbum.album.images[0].url + 
                  '">';
                     html += '</li>';

                    var id = eachAlbum.album.id;
                         console.log(id);   // all albums id's are showing 
                      in console

                    }); // closes each
                     html += '</ul>';

                      $("#albumImages").html(html);

                    } //closes displayAlbums function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store as data attribute on each `<img>` or `<li>`

```
html += '<img data-album_id="' +eachAlbum.album.id +'" src="' + eachAlbum.album.images[0].url + '">';
```

Then a click handler can access it directly from the element itself

```
$("#albumImages").on('click', '.albumImage img', function(){
   console.log('album id=', $(this).data('album_id'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-id` attributes on `img` or `li`, whichever makes sense inside your `$.each` and access them in `onclick` listener, like this:

```
function displayAlbums(data) {

    var html = '<ul>';
    $.each(data.tracks, function(i, eachAlbum) {
        html += '<li class="albumImage">';
        html += `<img src="${eachAlbum.album.images[0].url}" data-id="${eachAlbum.album.id}">`;
        html += '</li>';

        var id = eachAlbum.album.id;
        console.log(id); // all albums id's are showing in console

    }); // closes each
    html += '</ul>';

    $("#albumImages").html(html);

}
```

More on [using data attributes(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

More on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), as used here

```
html += `<img src="${.....`
```

Comment: That is helpful.  Thank you. I have got each album to have its id identified, but I am struggling to connect the album id to other information.  When I click on the image in my gallery I want that album's title to appear.  can $(this) be used in some way to access the title on image click?

Comment: If it's just the title that you want, just have that in a `data-title` attribute as well. If that "information" is a lot more than title (eg: comments, likes etc.) then assuming you've got the album id through `data-id`, get a hook on that object, it's as easy as: `var album = data.tracks.find(album => id === album.album.id)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the id as a data-id attribute, so it would look like this:

```
html += '<img src="' + eachAlbum.album.images[0].url + '" data-id="' + eachAlbum.album.id + '">';
```